# rpm update: what happens to modified files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

What happens at `rpm -U ..` if any file of the package being updated has been modified? Is it left updated with a new one, or the new (modified) file is kept with new extension?

Comment: @Rob sorry but 839 questions disagree with you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpmbuild . Yes, there are more on the Unix.SE but plenty here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM will overwrite any files that have changed *unless* they are explicitly designated as "configuration" files using the `%config` flag. Then it will make a copy of either the new one (`*.rpmnew`) or the old one (`*.rpmsave`) based on whether or not the config file is flagged as `noreplace`. See [this reference](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejw35/docs/rpm_config.html) for more details.